# Please retag memcache as memcached

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, retagging

The [memcache](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memcache) should be [memcached](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memcached). This is a very common mistake. However, [the right name is memcached](http://memcached.org/).

I also suggest to add [memcache](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memcache) as synonym of [memcached](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memcached), [as in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/memcached/synonyms).

Comment: "Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2." Although this is a good idea because there are so few questions let alone answerers who have the score needed, it might be a while before this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[memcache](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memcache)is now a synonym for [memcached](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memcached)and all questions tagged with [memcache](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memcache) are now tagged with [memcached](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memcached).

Comment: Should this and similar meta questions be ratagged with `status-completed` ?